# SubResource Integrity in Flask application

Tags: python, flask

Is there any package in python related to flask, that would generate sri token automatically and handle them?

I tried searching the Flask documentation and am not able to find it.

Please let me know how to do it if there is a way or should I do it manually.

Solution :

1. Function to generate the hash value

   def generate_sri(inp_file):
       BUF_SIZE = 65536
       hashed = hashlib.sha256()

   ```
   with open(inp_file, 'rb') as f:
       while True:
           data = f.read(BUF_SIZE)
           if not data:
               break
           hashed.update(data)
   hashed = hashed.digest()
   hash_base64 = base64.b64encode(hashed).decode('utf-8')
   return 'sha256-{}'.format(hash_base64)
   ```

   2. Add the function to the jinja env globals

`app.jinja_env.globals['sri'] = generate_sri`

3. Invoke the function within the template

`<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='file.js') }}" integrity="{{ sri(url_for('static', filename='file.js')) }}" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: Good question.  Would be really cool if this was integrated with webassets.  According to [this](https://www.srihash.org/) you can generate the hash with: `openssl dgst -sha384 -binary FILENAME.js | openssl base64 -A` but afaik there's nothing already that ties all this together.

Comment: I was looking for a third-party package that would serve the purpose, just like django-staticinline that is used to generate csrf, sri etc tokens with django.

Comment: See my [post on webassets github](https://github.com/miracle2k/webassets/issues/494#issuecomment-470326675) which has the Python to generate the hash, if that's any help.

Comment: Thanks. I used your example and wrote a function to generate the hash and added it to the jinja globals. Now I can just use the function inside the template to get the hash.

Comment: Nice! Could you [gist](https://gist.github.com/) the code, or post your solution here?

Comment: Follow the below link for gist

[link](https://gist.github.com/MaddysonBlaze/079400c4753d95a6924a5430f5fb56ce)